# Data from multiple excel sheets into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I'm relatively new to using sql and have a question.

I have 4 excel sheets, each 99 lines long with 4 columns. I imported these into sql server and have 4 seperate tables now. Fields are;

Brand, CL, Budget and Year.

tables are : Hotel, KASum, Offtrade and Ontrade

Each sheet (also each table as well) represent one sales channel.

I need to create a report about the sales of each channel. In order to do this i'm trying to build a query. So far i put all the data into one temp table but can't manage to seperate them according to their channels now. Any help?

PS: I hope my definition is clear and excuse my language if i have any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a column to each sheet indicating the channel before you upload. Or maybe during the upload depending on how you're doing that. So that the Hotel sheet would have a column that has "Hotel" all the way down. Now you can merge then without losing the original channel info.